# How to see json data on node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I want to use twitter api and so I download [this](https://github.com/BoyCook/TwitterJSClient) and as it mentioned on usage I create a js file and run it on `node.js` I except from it produce the `json` and see on console `json` data but I saw that on console:

```
URL [https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=1]
ERROR [[object Object]]
URL [https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json?count=1]
ERROR [[object Object]]
URL [https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=UfuK_GariP&count=1]
ERROR [[object Object]]
URL [https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json?count=1]
ERROR [[object Object]]
URL [https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweets_of_me.json?count=1]
ERROR [[object Object]]
```

Comment: And I want free beer for the rest of my life. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need output serialized content like this

```
console.log('ERROR [%s]', JSON.stringify(err));
```

Comment: Have you restarted node server ? What data you see ? still `[object Object]` ?

Comment: i got this error ERROR [{"statusCode":400,"data":"{\"errors\":[{\"code\":215,\"message\":\"Bad Authentication data.\"}]}"} how to fix that

Comment: Check your config for OAuth properties, it's a problem with Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can save some chars using

```
console.dir(err);
```

unlike

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
```

You have also some options like coloring, see [documentation.](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_dir_obj_options)